# Многоуровнёвое меню в массиве

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, шаблонизаторы

Нужно сделать трёхуровнёвое меню для интернет-магазина, которое будет открываться по клику.

1. Как сделать многомерный массив, в котором будут только названия этих пунктов 3х уровневого меню?  А в html, допустим с помощью шаблонизатора ejs брать данные из этого многомерного массива, и формировать меню.т.е. интересует именно создание этого массива, в котором будут названия меню, расположенные по уровню вложенности.
2. Как правильно создать это меню, чтобы потом можно было в цикле создавать многомерное меню из этого массива?
3. Приведите пожалуйста простой пример массива с многоуровнёвым меню.

Я так понимаю тут нужно использовать объект, в котором ключ будет как отдельное меню?
Что-то на подобии такого нужно сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<%
    let catalog = [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Наборы для творчества',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Научные игры',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            title: 'Настольные игры',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            title: 'Демонстрационные материалы',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 5,
            title: 'Раздаточные материалы',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 6,
            title: 'Рабочие тетради',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 7,
            title: 'Плакаты и таблицы',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 8,
            title: 'Оформление интерьера детского сада',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 9,
            title: 'Портфели, портфолио, детские анкеты',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 10,
            title: 'Для детской комнаты',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 11,
            title: 'Канцтовары',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 12,
            title: 'Новогодние товары',
            parent: 0
        },
        {
            id: 13,
            title: 'Большие наборы для творчества',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id: 14,
            title: 'Наборы для творчества из гипса',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id: 15,
            title: 'Картинки из песка, блесток, пайеток',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id: 16,
            title: 'HANDMADE - декор своими руками',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id: 17,
            title: 'Наборы для творчества на любой вкус',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id: 18,
            title: 'Наборы для слепков',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id: 19,
            title: 'Гравюры',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id: 20,
            title: 'Роспись по холсту',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id: 21,
            title: 'Раскраски и наклейки',
            parent: 1
        },
        {
            id: 22,
            title: 'Раскраски',
            parent: 13
        },
        {
            id: 23,
            title: 'Альбомы с наклейками',
            parent: 13
        },
        {
            id: 24,
            title: 'Наборы наклеек',
            parent: 13
        }
    ]

    for(let i = 0; i < catalog.length; i++){ %>
        <% if(catalog[i]['parent'] == 0) { %>
        <li><%- catalog[i]['title'] %></li>
        <% } else {%>
        <ul>
            <li><%- catalog[i]['title'] %></li>
        </ul>
    <% }}

 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вовсе не обязательно хранить его в многоуровневом массиве. Достаточно одноуровневого,и выводить с указанием некоего (условно) `parent_id`.  Неограниченная вложенность гарантирована :) а многомерный массив это тонны `forEach`, вложенных друг в друга, или рекурсия, или ещё много чего страшного. ИМХО

Например (псевдокод):

```
array = [
    [0] = [
        'title' = 'Телефоны',
        'parent_id' = NULL
    ],
    [1] = [
        'title' = 'ASUS',
        'parent_id' = 0
    ],
    [2] = [
        'title' = 'Автомобили',
        'parent_id' = NULL
    ],
    [3] = [
        'title' = 'Nissan',
        'parent_id' = 2
    ],
    [4] = [
        'title' = 'Samsung',
        'parent_id' = 0
    ],
    [5] = [
        'title' = 'Infiniti',
        'parent_id' = 2
    ],
    [6] = [
        'title' = 'Galaxy Note 3',
        'parent_id' = 4
    ]
]
```

Вот смотрите. У нас две корневых категории - это **Телефоны** и **Автомобили**, у них `parent_id` либо равен `NULL`, либо можно вообще не задавать, типа они никуда не вложены, корневые. Дальше у нас **ASUS** и **Samsung** вложены в `parent_id=0`, то есть в **Телефоны**. `parent_id` совпадает с индексом элемента, в который он вложен. **Nissan** и **Infiniti** вложены в **Автомобили**, `parent_id=2`. Это второй уровень. И третий уровень вложенности - **Galaxy Note 3**, он вложен в категорию **Samsung**, которая вложена в корневую категорию **Телефоны**.

Comment: а parent_id должен быть ключ или значение?
Есть ли где посмотреть на пример?

Comment: @word дополнил свой ответ подробностями. если остались ещё вопросы - давайте :)

Comment: дополнил ответ. Подскажите, как влаживать уровни меню в родителя?

Comment: @word прошу прощения, что значит "влаживать"?

Comment: "Капитан Флинт, вы ведь сами сказали использовать parent_id, а это значит что дочернее меню вложено в родительское.  Получается, в моём примере нужен второй цикл? одним циклом не обойтись

Comment: @word зачем? одним циклом идёте по массиву и "вкладываете" элементы на уровне манипуляций с DOM. Ваш пункт меню - это некий `<div>`, в котором лежат другие `<div>`. Вот и всё. Идёте по массиву, проверяете - если `parent_id` задан, то берёте элемент ну блин условно добавляете новый `<div>` с этим элементом в тот `<div>`, который соответствует родительскому пункту. Смотрите в сторону **jQuery** например для упрощения манипуляций с DOM.

Comment: как можно манипулировать dom, если список меню формируется в ejs? Это ведь не javascript! т.е. вы предлагаете сформировать сначала список меню в цикле, а потом с помощью jquery ещё в одном цикле манипулировать dom? Представьте, если многоуровнёвое меню состоит из 1000 подпунктов. Получается, что нужно 1000 манипуляций с dom. По идее это сильно накладно

Comment: покажите пожалуйста пример

Comment: @word а, прошу прощения. Сначала не понял про `ejs` ибо не особо занимаюсь яваскриптом. Я в общем виде написал как я бы это сделал, имея в виду в первую очередь хранение такого рода данных

Comment: так покажете, как это сделать?

Comment: @word что именно?

Comment: как формировать меню из массива в цикле с помощью ejs? я вверху привёл пример массива